# Submit Form Data without Reloading page

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I know this question has been asked and answered a bunch of times but for the life of me i can not get a solution to work on my code.  I believe if i REDO all my code, i will eventually get it to work properly, and in retrospect with as much time as I've spent on this issue i should have redone all my code...BUT i am now well beyond my deadline and just have to get a working prototype up...

Can anyone advise how to update multiple forms on a single page without reloading the page? I am horrible at PHP and complete noob with JS/JQuery/AJAX at BEST. my html/php are in a single file and i believe this is causing me the most problems/is the largest obstacle at getting my AJAX form processing to work.

Basically, I want users to:

1. Select teams from multiple dropdowns in Form Group 1 (league champs) and on update UPDATE my DB with the newly selected team without reloadding the page.
2. Edit team scores per match and on score submit/update, UPDATE the DB with new scores.

for each requirement there are multiple forms (1 each for leagues, 1 each per match) so i have set a class on each form as well as an id.

Everything works via PHP, but the form submission obviously reloads page each time something is submitted and this is not ideal.

i have tried the AJAX code from here http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery as well as numerous solutions from SO with no luck.  I don't know enough to know HOW to edit the code to work for my situation.

I'm not sure what code would help someone answer this as ALL my code is in a single page and would prob be too long to copy/paste in this post.  I will provide any info/data someone needs to help me with this. I'm 7 weeks past delivery (it's a personal project for me and friends so not too big of deal...but really want to be done with this).

Ok here is my code.  It's awful, and I am in process of refactoring it to utilize functions and and better queries, etc. But this is what I have currently and was hoping to make "work" before I reworked it...(the sections i wish to update per my question are commented with STACKOVERFLOW in the comment).  Hopefully this helps someone help me, as I am still at an impasse.

```
<?php
// includes and session data here

// Connect to DB

// get current date and time
$cur_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
require_once('current_week.php'); // this file contains $cur_week and $cur_date vars

// Grab the match id for each match to use for userpicks check/populate
$query_matchids = "SELECT id AS match_id FROM matches ORDER BY match_time";
$data_matchids = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_matchids)
or die('Error querying matches table for the match ids.');
$match_ids = array();
while ($row_matchids = mysqli_fetch_array($data_matchids)) {
array_push($match_ids, $row_matchids['match_id']);
}

// Check if USERPICKS exist
$query_userpicks = "SELECT user_id AS userpicks_userid, match_id AS userpicks_matchid, team_id_winner AS userpicks_winnerid, " .
"home_score AS userpicks_hscore, away_score AS userpicks_ascore " .
"FROM user_picks " .
"WHERE user_id = $user_id";
$data_userpicks = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_userpicks) 
or die('Error querying user_picks table for user picks data.');
if (mysqli_num_rows($data_userpicks) == 0) {
// If no userpicks exist for user, populate users picks' list with null data for each match
foreach ($match_ids AS $match_id) {
$query_userpicks_initial = "INSERT INTO user_picks (user_id, match_id) " .
"VALUES ($user_id, $match_id)";
mysqli_query($dbc, $query_userpicks_initial) 
or die('Error querying user_picks table to insert empty userpicks data.');
}
}
// if userpicks do exist for user, put data into an array to be used later
$userpicks = array();
while ($row_userpicks = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data_userpicks)) {
array_push($userpicks, $row_userpicks);
}

// Grab Week data from SEASON_WEEKS table to display matches and week views for pagination
$query_weeks = "SELECT week_number AS week, start_date AS week_start, end_date AS week_end FROM season_weeks ORDER BY start_date";
$data_weeks = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_weeks)
or die('Error querying season_weeks table for week data.');
$weeks = array();
while ($row_weeks = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data_weeks)) {
array_push($weeks, $row_weeks);
}
// total number of weeks in season...this SHOULD be total number of rows in season column...edit this to something more accurate if not
$num_weeks = mysqli_num_rows($data_weeks);

// Grab League Data
$query_leagues = "SELECT * FROM leagues";
$data_leagues = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_leagues)
or die('Error querying leagues table.');
$leagues = array();
while ($row_leagues = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data_leagues)) {
array_push($leagues, $row_leagues);
}

// Grab MATCH and RESULTS data to generate the Matches and Results
$query_matches = "SELECT m.id, m.match_time, m.home_team_id, m.away_team_id, m.league_id, " .
"l.name AS league_name, l.league_abbr, l.start_date AS league_start, l.end_date AS league_end, l.img_lrg AS league_crestlg, l.img_icon AS league_crestsm, " .
"h.name AS home_team, h.team_abbr AS home_abbr, h.stadium, h.img_lrg AS home_crestlg, h.img_icon AS home_crestsm, h.website AS home_url, " .
"a.name AS away_team, a.team_abbr AS away_abbr, a.img_lrg AS away_crestlg, a.img_icon AS away_crestsm, a.website AS away_url, " .
"mr.result_home, mr.home_score, mr.result_away, mr.away_score, mr.pks, mr.pks_home, mr.pks_away, " .
"up.match_id AS user_matchid, up.team_id_winner AS user_winnerid, up.home_score AS user_hscore, up.away_score AS user_ascore " .
"FROM matches AS m " .
"JOIN leagues AS l " .
"ON m.league_id = l.id " .
"JOIN teams AS h " .
"ON m.home_team_id = h.id " .
"JOIN teams AS a " .
"ON m.away_team_id = a.id " .
"LEFT JOIN match_results AS mr " .
"ON m.id = mr.match_id " .
"LEFT JOIN user_picks AS up " .
"ON m.id = up.match_id AND up.user_id = '$user_id' " .
"ORDER BY league_id, match_time";
$data_matches = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_matches) 
or die('Error querying matches, teams, and match_results tables for match data.');
$matches = array();
while ($row_matches = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data_matches)) {
array_push($matches, $row_matches);
}

// Grab points data from ace_points


?>
<section class="container">
<div class="row">
<h1 class="text-center col-xs-12"><?php echo $page_main_header; ?></h1>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div class="container champions_container">
<div class="row">
<button type="button" id="league_champs_button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-12" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#champs_selections_container">Select League Champions</button>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div id="champs_selections_container" class="collapse">
<?php
// Grab Champions Pick Data for each League per user
foreach ($leagues AS $league) {
// grab teams for this league
$query_teams = "SELECT id, name FROM teams WHERE league_id = '" . $league['id'] . "'";
$data_teams = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_teams) 
or die('Error querying teams table for team data.');
$teams = array();
while ($row_teams = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data_teams)) {
array_push($teams, $row_teams);
}
// Check Champion Picks to see if a champion has been selected
$query_champions = "SELECT league_id, team_id, pts_value FROM champ_picks WHERE user_id = $user_id AND league_id = '" . $league['id'] . "'";
$data_champions = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_champions)
or die('Error querying champ_picks table for Chamions data.');
$champions = array();
while ($row_champions = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data_champions)) {
array_push($champions, $row_champions);
}
$champ_points = ($champ_orig_points - ($cur_week * 2));
// if a champion exists in user's champ_picks, set variables accordingly
if (mysqli_num_rows($data_champions) == 1) {
$user_champ = $champions[0]['team_id'];
if ($champions[0]['pts_value'] === NULL) {
$user_champ_pts = 0;
}
else {
$user_champ_pts = $champions[0]['pts_value'];
}

}
else {
// No Champion selected for this league yet
$user_champ = '';
$user_champ_pts = 0;
} 
// TODO: if CHAMP PICKS change, UPDATE edited selections only - via AJAX
/* STACKOVERFLOW - CHAMPIONS */
// if user submits form UPDATE champ_picks table with new champion selection(s)
if (isset($_POST['champs_submit_league' . $league['id']])) {
$league_id = $_POST['leagueid'][0];
$updated_champs = $_POST['champions'][0];
$updated_champs_pts = $champ_points;
$query_champs_update = "UPDATE champ_picks SET team_id = '$updated_champs', pts_value = '$updated_champs_pts' WHERE league_id = '$league_id'";
mysqli_query($dbc, $query_champs_update)
or die('Error querying champs_picks to update champions for ' . $league['name'] . '.');
}
else {
//echo 'Post not set for Champions ' . $league['id'] . '<br />';
}
?>
<form method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="champ_picks_league<?php echo $league['id']; ?>" class="col-xs-12">
<div class="form-group col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-12">
<label class="sr-only" for="mousetrap_champs<?php echo $league['id']; ?>">Leave Blank <span class="required">(required to prove you are human)</span></label>
<input class="sr-only form-control" type="text" id="mouestrap_champs<?php echo $league['id']; ?>" name="mousetrap_champs<?php echo $league['id']; ?>" value="<?php if(!empty($spam_protect)) echo $spam_protect; ?>" placeholder="Leave blank" />
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-12">
<input type="hidden" id="leagueid<?php echo $league['id']; ?>" name="leagueid[]" value="<?php echo $league['id']; ?>" />
<label class="sr-only" for="champions"><?php echo $league['name']; ?> Champs</label>
<div class="input-group" style="position: relative;">
<select class="form-control" id="champions<?php echo $league['id']?>" name="champions[]">
<?php echo 'Champs: ' . $user_champ; ?>
<option value="" <?php if (empty($user_champ)) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo $league['name']; ?> Champs</option>
<?php
foreach ($teams as $team) {
// FIXIT: if POST is set per league pick, show newly updated champion team selection -current code isnt working to do this
//  if (isset($_POST) && $updated_champs == $team['id']) {
//      $select_option = 'selected="selected"';
//      echo '<option value="' . $team['id'] . '" ' . $select_option . '>' . $team['name'] . ' (current pick)</option>';
//  }
if (!empty($user_champ) && $user_champ == $team['id']) {
$select_option = 'selected="selected"';
echo '<option class="current_userpick" value="' . $team['id'] . '" ' . $select_option . '>' . $team['name'] . ' (current pick)</option>';
}
else {
$select_option = '';
echo '<option value="' . $team['id'] . '" ' . $select_option . '>' . $team['name'] . '</option>';
}                                           
}
?>
</select>
<span class="input-group-addon champ_points_display"><?php echo $champ_points; ?> (<?php echo $user_champ_pts; ?>)</span>
<?php 
// only show UPDATE button if user has agreed to RULES already
if ($_SESSION['user_rules'] == 'Y') {
?>
<input type="submit" id="champs_submit_league<?php echo $league['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-lrg btn-block form-control input-group-addon" name="champs_submit_league<?php echo $league['id']; ?>" value="Update" />
<?php
}
?>
<!-- TODO: move this to a seperate file, disable UPDATE button if user re-selects original USERPICK champ -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#league_champs_button").click(function() {
$("input#champs_submit_league<?php echo $league['id']; ?>").css("display", "none");
});
$("#champions<?php echo $league['id']?>").change(function() {
$("input#champs_submit_league<?php echo $league['id']; ?>").fadeIn(1000);
});
});
</script>
</div>
</div>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Week Pagination - only show if have more than 1 week of matches-->
<?php 
if ($num_weeks > 1) {
?>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
<ul class="pagination">
<!-- pagination goes here -->
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
}
// loop through each week of season(s)
foreach ($weeks as $week) {
if (isset($_GET['week']) && $_GET['week'] == $week['week']) {
?>
<div class="container week_container">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div class="row week_heading">
<h3 class="col-xs-12">WEEK <?php echo $week['week']; ?></h3>
<p class="col-xs-12"><?php echo date("F j", strtotime($week['week_start'])) . ' - ' . date("F j, Y", strtotime($week['week_end'])); ?></p>
</div>

<?php
// loop through each League
foreach ($leagues AS $league) {
$league_id = $league['id'];
$league_name = $league['name'];
$league_abbr = $league['league_abbr'];
$league_start = $league['start_date'];
$league_end = $league['end_date'];
$league_crestlg = $league['img_lrg'];
$league_crestsm = $league['img_icon'];
$league_img_dir = ACE_IMAGE_UPLOADPATH . strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $league['name'])) . '/';
// Make sure matches exist for given league and given week...only display leagues with matches that week
$query_league_matches = "SELECT id FROM matches WHERE league_id = '$league_id' AND DATE(match_time) >= '" . $week['week_start'] . "' AND DATE(match_time) <= '" . $week['week_end'] . "'";
$result_league_matches = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_league_matches) 
or die('Error querying matches for number of league matches in given week.');
if (mysqli_num_rows($result_league_matches) > 0) {
?>
<div class="row league_container">
<div class="row">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion_league<?php echo $league_id; ?>">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion_league<?php echo $league_id; ?>" href="#collapse_league<?php echo $league_id; ?>"><?php echo $league_name; ?> Matches</a></h4>
</div>
<div id="collapse_league<?php echo $league_id; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<div class="panel-body">
<?php
// Create Match variables
foreach ($matches as $match) {
$match_id = $match['id'];
$match_time = $match['match_time'];
$match_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($match_time)); // to use for grabbing matches for a given week
$match_time_convert = strtotime($match_time); // convert user input time to a UNIX timestamp so i can convert to a diff format to display
$match_time_readable = date('g:ia', $match_time_convert);
$match_date_readable = date('l F j, Y', $match_time_convert);
$match_leagueid = $match['league_id'];
$league_name = $match['league_name'];
$home_team = $match['home_team'];
$home_abbr = $match['home_abbr'];
$home_id = $match['home_team_id'];
$home_crestlg = $match['home_crestlg'];
$home_crestsm = $match['home_crestsm'];
$home_url = $match['home_url'];
$stadium = $match['stadium'];
$away_team = $match['away_team'];
$away_abbr = $match['away_abbr'];
$away_id = $match['away_team_id'];
$away_crestlg = $match['away_crestlg'];
$away_crestsm = $match['away_crestsm'];
$away_url = $match['away_url'];
$result_home = $match['result_home'];
$result_away = $match['result_away'];
$score_home = $match['home_score'];
$score_away = $match['away_score'];
$pks = $match['pks'];
$pks_home = $match['pks_home'];
$pks_away = $match['pks_away'];
$user_match_id = $match['user_matchid'];
$user_winner_id = $match['user_winnerid'];
$user_score_home = $match['user_hscore'];
$user_score_away = $match['user_ascore'];
// set winner variable
if ($result_home == 'W') { // HOME team win
$winner = $home_team;
$winner_id = $home_id;
}
elseif ($result_away == 'W') { // AWAY team win
$winner = $away_team;
$winner_id = $away_id;
}
else { // Draw
$winner = '';
$winner_id = '';
}
// TODO: if MATCH SCORES change, UPDATE edited selections only - via AJAX
/* STACKOVERFLOW - MATCH SCORE UPDATES */
// if user edits match scores UPDATE userpicks table with new scores and winner picks
if (isset($_POST['picks_submit' . $match_id])) {
$picks_matchid = $_POST['picks_matchids'][$match_id];
$picks_hscore = $_POST['home_scores'][$match_id];
$picks_homeid = $_POST['home_ids'][$match_id];
$picks_ascore = $_POST['away_scores'][$match_id];
$picks_awayid = $_POST['away_ids'][$match_id];
if ((!empty($picks_hscore)) && (!empty($picks_ascore))) {
// set winner variable
if ($picks_hscore > $picks_ascore) { // HOME team win
$picks_winnerid = $picks_homeid;
}
elseif ($picks_ascore > $picks_hscore) { // AWAY team win
$picks_winnerid = $picks_awayid;
}
else { // Draw
$picks_winner = 'DRAW';
$picks_winnerid = '-1';
}
$query_score_update = "UPDATE user_picks " .
"SET team_id_winner = '$picks_winnerid', home_score = '$picks_hscore', away_score = '$picks_ascore' " .
"WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND match_id = '$picks_matchid'";
mysqli_query($dbc, $query_score_update)
or die('Error querying user_picks to update scores for Match #' . $match_id . '.');
}
elseif ((empty($picks_hscore)) && (!empty($picks_ascore))) { // if home score is empty
// TODO: echo errors for missing score data
}
else { // if away score is empty
// TODO: echo errors for missing score data
}
}
//else {
// DO I NEED ANYTHING IF POST IS NOT SET?
//}
// Display this week's matches
if (($match_leagueid == $league_id) && ($match_date >= $week['week_start']) && ($match_date <= $week['week_end'])) {
if (($cur_time > $match_time)) {
echo '<div class="row match_container past_match">';
}
else {
echo '<div class="row match_container">';
}
?>
<ul class="match_info col-md-2 col-xs-12">
<li class="match_date"><span class="label">Date</span><?php echo date("D. M. j", strtotime($match_time)); ?></li>
<li class="match_time"><span class="label">Kickoff</span><?php echo date("g:ia", strtotime($match_time)); ?></li>
<li class="stadium"><span class="label">Stadium</span><?php echo $stadium; ?></li>
<li class="league_logo"><span class="label">League</span>
<?php
if (!empty($league_crestsm)) {
echo '<img src="' . $league_img_dir . 'crests/' . $league_crestsm . '" alt="' . $league_name . ' logo" title="This is a ' . $league_name . ' match." /></li>';
}
else {
echo $league_name;
}
?>
</li>
</ul>
<form method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="form_match<?php echo $match_id; ?>" class="teams_container col-md-8 col-xs-12">
<input type="hidden" min="0" class="form-control" id="picks_matchid_<?php echo $match_id; ?>" name="<?php echo 'picks_matchids[' . $match_id . ']'; ?>" value="<?php echo $match_id; ?>" />
<?php                                               // if results exist for this match, display them

// if no results exist for this match
else {
?>
<div>
<div class="home_team col-xs-5">
<div class="row">
<h4 class="col-xs-12 team_name"><?php echo $home_team; ?></h4>
<h4 class="col-xs-12 team_name team_abbreviation"><a href="<?php echo $home_url; ?>" rel="" title="Visit <?php echo $home_team; ?>'s website."><?php echo $home_abbr; ?></a></h4>
<p class="col-xs-12 team_url"><a href="<?php echo $home_url; ?>" rel="" title="Visit <?php echo $home_team; ?>'s website."><?php echo $home_url; ?></a></p>
</div>
<div class="row">
<img class="team_crest col-xs-6" src="<?php echo $league_img_dir; ?>crests/<?php echo $home_crestsm; ?>" alt="<?php echo $home_team; ?>'s crest" />
<div class="form-group home_score score col-xs-6">
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="homeid_<?php echo $home_id; ?>" name="<?php echo 'home_ids[' . $match_id . ']'; ?>" value="<?php echo $home_id; ?>" />
<label class="sr-only" for="home_score">Home Score</label>
<?php
// if current time is BEFORE match time, allow user to pick match results
if ($cur_time < $match_time) {
if ((!empty($user_score_home) || ($user_score_home === 0)) && ($_SESSION['user_rules'] == 'Y')) {
?>      
<!-- STACKOVERFLOW - MATCH SCORE UPDATES -->
<input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" id="home_score_<?php echo $match_id; ?>" name="<?php echo 'home_scores[' . $match_id . ']'; ?>" value="<?php echo $user_score_home; ?>" />

<?php
}
// if user has NOT yet agreed to RULES, do not allow user to pick match results
elseif ((!empty($user_score_home) || ($user_score_home === 0)) && ($_SESSION['user_rules'] == 'N')) {
?>

<input type="number" min="0" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" id="home_score_<?php echo $match_id; ?>" name="<?php echo 'home_scores[' . $match_id . ']'; ?>" value="<?php echo $_POST['home_scores'][$match_id]; ?>" />
<?php
}
else {
?>
<input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" id="home_score_<?php echo $match_id; ?>" name="<?php echo 'home_scores[' . $match_id . ']'; ?>" value="<?php echo $_POST['home_scores'][$match_id]; ?>" />
<?php           
}
}
// if current time is AFTER match time and match OVER, DO NOT allow user to pick match results
elseif ($cur_time >= date('Y-m-d H:i', (strtotime('+95 minutes', strtotime($match_time))))) {
?>
<input type="number" min="0" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" id="home_score_<?php echo $match_id; ?>" name="<?php echo 'home_scores[' . $match_id . ']'; ?>" value="<?php echo $user_score_home; ?>" />
<p class="alert-danger post_match_warning">Results pending.</p>
<?php
}
// if current time is AFTER match time but match still playing, DO NOT allow user to pick match results
else {
?>
<input type="number" min="0" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" id="home_score_<?php echo $match_id; ?>" name="<?php echo 'home_scores[' . $match_id . ']'; ?>" value="<?php echo $user_score_home; ?>" />
<p class="alert-danger post_match_warning">Too Late.</p>
<?php

}
?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<p class="versus_text col-xs-2">vs</p>
<div class="away_team col-xs-5">
<div class="row">
<h4 class="col-xs-12 team_name"><?php echo $away_team; ?></h4>
<h4 class="col-xs-12 team_name team_abbreviation"><a href="<?php echo $away_url; ?>" rel="" title="Visit <?php echo $away_team; ?>'s website."><?php echo $away_abbr; ?></a></h4>
<p class="col-xs-12 team_url"><a href="<?php echo $away_url; ?>" rel="" title="Visit <?php echo $away_team; ?>'s website."><?php echo $away_url; ?></a></p>
</div>
<div class="row">
<img class="team_crest col-xs-6" src="<?php echo $league_img_dir; ?>crests/<?php echo $away_crestsm; ?>" alt="<?php echo $away_team; ?>'s crest" />
<div class="form-group away_score score col-xs-6">
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="awayid_<?php echo $away_id; ?>" name="<?php echo 'away_ids[' . $match_id . ']'; ?>" value="<?php echo $away_id; ?>" />
<label class="sr-only" for="away_score">Away Score</label>
<?php
// if current time is BEFORE match time, allow user to pick match results
if ($cur_time < $match_time) {
if ((!empty($user_score_away) || ($user_score_away === 0)) && ($_SESSION['user_rules'] == 'Y')) {
?>      
<!-- STACKOVERFLOW - MATCH SCORE UPDATES -->
<input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" id="away_score_<?php echo $match_id; ?>" name="<?php echo 'away_scores[' . $match_id . ']'; ?>" value="<?php echo $user_score_away; ?>" />
<?php
}
// if user has NOT yet agreed to RULES, do not allow user to pick match results
elseif ((!empty($user_score_away) || ($user_score_away === 0)) && ($_SESSION['user_rules'] == 'N')) {
?>
<input type="number" min="0" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" id="away_score_<?php echo $match_id; ?>" name="<?php echo 'away_scores[' . $match_id . ']'; ?>" value="<?php echo $_POST['away_scores'][$match_id]; ?>" />
<?php
}
else {
?>

<input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" id="away_score_<?php echo $match_id; ?>" name="<?php echo 'away_scores[' . $match_id . ']'; ?>" value="<?php echo $_POST['away_scores'][$match_id]; ?>" />
<?php           
}
}
// if current time is AFTER match time and match OVER, DO NOT allow user to pick match results
elseif ($cur_time >= date('Y-m-d H:i', (strtotime('+95 minutes', strtotime($match_time))))) {
?>
<input type="number" min="0" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" id="away_score_<?php echo $match_id; ?>" name="<?php echo 'away_scores[' . $match_id . ']'; ?>" value="<?php echo $user_score_away; ?>" />
<p class="alert-danger post_match_warning">Results pending.</p>
<?php
}
// if current time is AFTER match time but match still playing, DO NOT allow user to pick match results
else {
?>
<input type="number" min="0" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" id="away_score_<?php echo $match_id; ?>" name="<?php echo 'away_scores[' . $match_id . ']'; ?>" value="<?php echo $user_score_away; ?>" />
<p class="alert-danger post_match_warning">Too Late.</p>
<?php

}
?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
}
if (($cur_time < $match_time) && ($_SESSION['user_rules'] == 'Y')) {
?>
<!-- STACKOVERFLOW - MATCH SCORE UPDATES -->
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-12">
<input type="submit" id="picks_submit<?php echo $match_id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-lrg btn-block form-control submit" name="picks_submit<?php echo $match_id; ?>" value="Update Match" />
</div>
</div>
<!-- further code here -->
</form><!-- end .TEAMS_CONTAINER/score input form -->

</div><!-- ends .PAST_MATCH div -->
<!-- remaining code is below here -->
```

Comment: Post your code you are having trouble with, we won't write the solution from scratch for you

Comment: You need to learn to code all of the languages that you have mentioned, or at least have a basic understanding of them all and how they hang together, else you're not going to be able to achieve anything.

Comment: If Jquery than `$.ajax()` it is pretty well documented even for beginers. But basicly you need a file or function in php that updates your DB and the form data which you post to that file or function

Comment: SO puts code in a scrollable window, so length is no issue. Please post the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

Comment: @coulton i am in process of trying to learn JS and PHP, and as a result AJAX. Unfortunately, at the time i decided to build this, i didn't think of the necessity of using AJAX to update the scores without reloading the page - actually it wasn't even a concern as my first iteration i only had 10 matches per week in a single form with a single SUBMIT button so the page load wasn't an issue.  After developing the site, that changed and i find myself under skilled to complete the score uploads with Ajax, hence my question here. This is my first app from scratch and it's very close to what i want.

Comment: @Laci K I think my issue is having all my code in a single file thus making $.ajax difficult or impossible for me to utilize, i am working on rewriting my code now to break up the page into multiple function i can store on separate files so i can more easily utilize jquery's $.ajax...work in progress that i wish i could have finished 7 weeks ago...

Comment: @Andy Holmes, i was not expecting a solution from scratch, but my code is SO spaghetti that posting it i think will elicit more negative feedback than assistance...but I have posted as requested and hopefully someone will be able to follow my code enough to suggest a viable fix to "make it work" while i rewrite the app to be cleaner...would love to have a working sample for the weekend...or at latest next wednesday

Comment: You don't need to split your code to multiple files as I wrote before you can have a function wich deals with your ajax data. for example like this: `<?php function test($param){//do something here} if(isset($_POST['something'])){$func = test($_POST['something']); echo $func; exit;} ?>` and in your ajax you don't need to specify `url` param and this way ajax will post the data to the same file.

Comment: @Laci K Iunfortunately i really don't understand your answer.  I appreciate the response, but really don't get it.  I have tried several methods of doing this already (many from stackoverflow, including the one referenced as a possible answer/duplicate) but have not had any semblance of success. I am considering scrapping the project and just starting over but this seems like a waste since i feel so close to being "done" with a functional site if i had the score uploads working with ajax. It's very frustrating. Any ideas of other useful tutorials explaining your answer in more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to explain it to you in an example and I hope you can make sense of it. *Sorry but your code is really long and not the best formated and I don't have time right now to make sense of it.*

Lets say you want to update a name in a DB table and you don't want to have multiple files.

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect('hostname', 'username', 'pass', 'dbname');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){ 
   echo 'connection error: ' . mysqli_connect_error(); 
}

function update($name, $id){
  mysqli_query($connect, 
  "UPDATE `my_user_table` SET `name`='$name' WHERE id=$id")
  or die(mysqli_error($connection));
  $success = '<p>Success</p>';
  return $success;
}

if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['id'])){
  $myupdate = update($_POST['name'], $_POST['id']);
  echo $myupdate;
  exit;
}
?>

<div id="formcont">
<form id="updateform" name="update" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</div>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('#submit').click(function(){ //or you can use on() instead of click()
    var formdata = $('#updateform').serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      cache: false, //or if you want cache delete this line
      data: formdata,
      success: function(data){
        //do whatever you want here
        //for example remove form and print a success text
        $('#updateform').remove();
        $('#formcont').append(data);
      }
    });
  return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

This is only one example how can you have your php function(s) in the same file and use ajax.